# Changing axes ticks in contourf (MatLab)

Tags: matlab, contourf

I've got the following code, which produces the graph below. Unfortunately, I can't share the data for this one.

```
time=data.time(); 
tim=find(time>0.0 & time<1.4) 
time(tim)

pow=mean(data.powspctrm,1);
pow=squeeze(pow);
pow(isnan(pow))=0;
pow2=pow(:,:);
Min = min(pow,[],'omitnan');
Min=min(Min);
Max = max(pow,[],'omitnan');
Max=max(Max);
contourf(time(tim),data.freq,pow2(:,tim),40,'linecolor','none');caxis([Min Max]);
colbar = colorbar
caxis([-.31 .31])
colbar.TickLabels = -30:10:30
xtickvec = -0.1:0.2:1.3
set(gca,'XTick',xtickvec)
```

I've been trying to change the y axis ticks to go until 30 the same way as I did for the x axis with `ytickvec = 5:5:30` then `set(gca,'YTick',ytickvec)` but it does nothing. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: To add to the above, in the code I posted, the last 2 lines that change the x axis ticks just stopped working suddenly. It just changes nothing. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: what command do you use to generate the 3D graph? surf?

Comment: Gosh, I'm so sorry and thanks for pointing this out! I've wiped out by mistake half a line. The command is ```contourf``` (now code edited).

Comment: Does it work with `xticks(xtickvec)` (see [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticks.html))? It's worth a try.

Comment: Not really. I tried changing to selected ticks, having a vector with them and assigning that to the axis (as above). But it just doesn't seem to react. I can manipulate the ticks of the colorbar easily though same way. At the end I just added a '30' with a visual editor on the final image.

Answer (score 0):

**1.-** `XTick` and `YTick` are available through the handle produced when invoking `gca`.

Using `gca` just after falling `figure(1);` works ok.

This way you can change `XTick` and `YTick` , example:

```
close all;clear all;clc

x = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi);
y = linspace(0,4*pi);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = sin(X) + cos(Y);

figure(1);
ax1=gca
[M,hc]=contourf(X,Y,Z,10)
```

[image]

```
ax1.XTick
ax1.YTick
```

here they are

```
 =
    -6    -4    -2     0     2     4     6
 =
     0     2     4     6     8    10    12
```

read and write, meaning you can also write `ax1.XTick` and `ax1.YTick`

**2.-** The same applies to the handle produced by `contourf`

The question has been answered, but often when working with contours one needs data contained in the handle returned by `contourf`, so I am including the following comment:

Modifying `contour` and `contourf` properties is easy using the handle provided when calling it using the following format

```
[M,hc]=contourf(..)
```

`hc` is the handle to the produced `contourf`

Noe you can do the following

```
hc.LineWidth = 3;
```

[image]

```
hc.LineWidth = .8;
hc.LineStyle='--'
```

[image]

**3.- When using handles **DO NOT** go back to directly modifying properties input fields**

If you now do for instance this

```
contourf(X,Y,Z,'--')
```

you are now you back to modifying properties in the function call of contours produced with `contourf` without the handle.

MATLAB will perform accordingly whatever you modify this way **BUT** the handle `hc` is going to be deleted.

Either stick to not using handles for local property modifications (nearby code lines) or use handles and avoid using direct modification of properties in the same function call.

In case of intending to use that handle again you can indeed generate again `hc` as many times as you want.